# Untangle NG Firewall DHCP options based on MAC address / IP address?

Tags: firewall, dhcp, dhcpd, untangle

We are trying to set DHCP options based on IP address.
Scenario: We have 50 systems in network and want to configure some systems with google DNS and other systems with internal DNS.

I tried below settings, but they are not working.

```
dhcp-range=set:red,192.168.2.50,192.168.2.150
dhcp-option = tag:red, option:dns-server, 8.8.4.4
```

Could anyone please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance